# Group messages between a start and stop event into distinct buckets in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am not able to find a way to aggregate messages into buckets the way I want to with  Elasticsearch.

I have log messages with a field that indicates whether it's a START or a STOP message and a timestamp. Now I want to aggregate the messages between the consecutive START and STOP messages into buckets like this:

```
START msg -
msg       |
msg       | Bucket 1
msg       |
STOP msg  -
START msg -
msg       |
msg       | Bucket 2
msg       |
STOP msg  -
```

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch, but I've gone through the documentation on Bucket aggregations and Pipeline aggregations and I don't see how I can for instance use the timestamp of the START and STOP messages to select the messages that need to go into the bucket.

Comment: I would probably do this as a pre-processing step before ingesting the data, for instance by using the [`aggregate` Logstash filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example1). Would something like this be conceivable for your use case?

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that, but as I understand it, that will simply result in a new document entry with the bucketed messages in the body of that document.
As I am writing this answer, I think of a solution where I can probably add a sort of bucketid to the messages so that I can group in elasticsearch later on. I am going to try that. Thanks for the rubberducking!

Comment: Yes, if you can add a bucket id to each document that solves the problem of course

Answer (score 0):

You can use filebeat to combine your multiline data and ingest into elasticsearch.

Check this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html

[image]

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but it's not multi-line messaging. The lines in themselves contain valuable standalone information.